# Asynchronous ftp client (file download) in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I create an automatic ftp file downloader by using FTPwebrequest. In which, is there any possible to download multiple files simultaneously using Asynchrounous and threading concept? . I need to some guidance or tutorials for asynchrounous ftp file download. Pls guide me.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this vb code could help:

```
' begin asynchronous transfer '
Dim asyncResult As IAsyncResult
asyncResult = ftp.BeginGetFile( _
    remotePath, _
    localPath, _
    New AsyncCallback(AddressOf MyCallback), _
    Nothing _
 )

Do 
    ' do something else here... '
Loop While Not asyncResult.IsCompleted

' get the result '
Dim bytes As Long 
bytes = ftp.EndGetFile(asyncResult)
```

code [source](http://www.rebex.net/ftp.net/sample-get-put-async.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can download file asynchronously from the internet by that code, but I don't know if that works on ftp. Anyway, give it a try.

```
Dim client as new webclient
AddHandler client.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf DownloadFileCallback 
client.downloadfileasync(New Uri("link"), _
                   path) 

Private Sub DownloadFileCallback(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
'What to do when the download was completed.
End sub
```

Hope the answer will help